# create a dynamic path to directorie /lib,

Tags: bash, bash4

Im trying to create a dynamic path to directorie /lib, but the code bellow is giving me a error, that the directorie does not exist.

```
user=$USER
home=$HOME

rsync -az /$home/$user/lib /media/x/x
```

Could somebody give me a tipp on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Try: `rsync -az $home/lib /media/x/x` HOME variable contains `/home/username`

Answer (score 0):

Echo out the value of your string that is represented by "/$home/$user/lib" and check if it is what you intended.

Have you tried this:

```
rsync -az $HOME/lib /media/x/x
```

The $HOME variable represents "/Users/username". By adding the preceding slash you get "//Users/username" and then by adding the username afterwards you get "//Users/username/username". I think that's your problem.

Comment: Your code is the same as mine. I have tried echo and Its giving me the wrong path...

Comment: Just checked it and updated the answer. The path should be correct now.

Comment: The new path is giving me root/lib the path has not such file or directorie